# How do I flush a class method in Rails 4 using memcached?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I have the following in a Rails 4 app:

```
class Update < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order('created_at desc') }

  after_commit :flush_cache

  def flush_cache
    Rails.cache.delete([self.class.name, 'latest'])
  end

  def self.cached_latest
    Rails.cache.fetch([self.class.name, 'latest']) { Update.all.limit(5) }
  end
end
```

But the cached is never flushed.  This cache shows the latest 5 updates added, but when I add a new one, it's not flushing the cache.

I've verified memcached is running.  This is in the development environment, but I have turned on caching for that environment.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: One more thing, I haven't tested this yet but i'm pretty sure, `Update.all.limit(5)` will only return the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object which will only fire the db call once you try to iterate over it or call `to_a` on it. So if you just change it to `Update.limit(5).to_a` then the db query will actually fire and return the actual objects which would be a better thing to do if you want to cache them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `self.class.name` in a class method and an instance method.

First, here's the solution, change `self.cached_latest` to:

```
def self.cached_latest
  Rails.cache.fetch([name, 'latest']) { Update.all.limit(5) }
end
```

In a self dot method (a class method) you're already in the `class` so calling `self.class` will return the class' class which would be `Class` and not `Update` as you're expecting (the name of your model class)

In the instance method `flush_cache` the call to `self.class.name` was correctly returning `Update`. So when you were `after_commit`ing, it was trying to flush the `['Update', 'latest']` cache key but your `self.cached_latest` class method was writing to the `['Class', 'latest']` cache key.

So, the problem was that you were calling `self.class.name` from two different contexts and it was returning a different value.

To improve upon your solution you could do away with the `after_commit` callback by using a self busting cache key:

```
def self.cached_latest
  Rails.cache.fetch([name, 'latest', count, order(updated_at: :desc).first.updated_at]) { Update.all.limit(5) }
end
```

This cache key would now look something like:

```
['Update', 'latest', 45, "date of latest record's updated_at timestamp"]
```

As you might be able to tell by now, this cache key would change as soon as you create or update a record, add an `expires` to it and you'll have a self flushing cache.